# Many to many has reputation gem scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the active record reputation system gem and I want to display a list of businesses from a certain category inside an estate with their associated votes.

So I have the following models

```
Business has many Categories through Categorizations
Category has many Businesses through Categorizations

Business has many Estates through Localizations
Estate has many Businesses through Localizations
```

In my business model I have

```
has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
```

I can get the businesses with their associated votes

```
@businesses = @estate.businesses.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: @category.id}).find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc")
```

but I want the votes to be estate specific i.e. when a business gets voted down in estate1 then his vote count in estate2 is not affected.

(I think this might be a larger problem than initially anticipated. Would I have to create another model that represents `estates_businesses` that `has_reputation`?)

Comment: Practicing `Stackoverflow-driven development` today, aren't you? :-D

Comment: Acutally I think you might need to take a look at the source for the `find_with_reputation` in the twitter/activerecord-reputation-system gem on Github for this question. A new model might not be nescessary, but maybe a custom `find_with_reputation` that takes that takes the situation into account.

Comment: It was such a complex problem that I had to ask it in stages. Is that frowned upon? New to dev. Can I pay you for your time to help with this last bit?

Comment: That's fine, no need to apologize. Well done by the way, solving your problem step by step. Email me and we could take a glimpse into the AR Reputation System source together.